# How do I take only parts of BeautifulSoup4's outputs and reformat it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to make a Torrent Magnet Link scraper. I've got the code to work to the point that it scrapes the information I need (the magnet link) but it also scrapes extra information such as the HTML tags (like href/title="..." etc). I would like the code to only output the magnet link, the size of the torrent, and the torrent's name, it would also be good if the output was indented between each individual torrent.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://eztv.io/'
response = requests.get(URL)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
magnet = content.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "magnet"})
print(magnet)
```

This is what the code output looks like:

```
CAFFEiNE%5Beztv%5D.mkv%5Beztv%5D&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" rel="nofollow" title="Marketplace S47E09 Locksmith Ripoffs Fake Listings Fake Reviews 720p WEB h264-CAFFEiNE [eztv] (577.03 MB) Magnet Link"></a>, <a class="magnet" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4ceaabd8ea97eed474a645d9d9223fe51f354ac3&amp;dn=Marketplace.S47E06.Are.Noisy.Restaurants.Harmful.to.Your.Health.480p.x264-mSD%5Beztv%5D.mkv%5Beztv%5D&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" rel="nofollow" title="Marketplace S47E06 Are Noisy Restaurants Harmful to Your Health 480p x264-mSD [eztv] (164.48 MB) Magnet Link"></a>, <a class="magnet" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0ca16cfac499bea3fa6bfd564484e90c38501aad&amp;dn=Marketplace.S47E08.Blinded.by.Blue.Lights-Banned.from.Seniors.Homes.WEB.h264-CAFFEiNE%5Beztv%5D.mkv%5Beztv%5D&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" rel="nofollow" title="Marketplace S47E08 Blinded by Blue Lights-Banned from Seniors Homes WEB h264-CAFFEiNE [eztv] (319.27 MB) Magnet Link"></a>, <a class="magnet" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:654c1dbb3be446ed3ebc1aff69d6ba1779577ce8&amp;dn=Marketplace.S47E08.Blinded.by.Blue.Lights-Banned.from.Seniors.Homes.720p.WEB.h264-CAFFEiNE%5Beztv%5D.mkv%5Beztv%5D&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" rel="nofollow" title="Marketplace S47E08 Blinded 
by Blue Lights-Banned from Seniors Homes 720p WEB h264-CAFFEiNE [eztv] (576.63 MB) Magnet Link"></a>, <a class="magnet" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:b3c5a40fe8484ebfa0790bc97d5fda77c6ba0a13&amp;dn=Marketplace.S47E07.Food.Fact-Check.WEB.h264-CAFFEiNE%5Beztv%5D.mkv%5Beztv%5D&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" rel="nofollow" title="Marketplace S47E07 Food Fact-Check WEB h264-CAFFEiNE [eztv] (319.01 MB) Magnet Link"></a>]
```

I'm using https://eztv.io/ to scrape the torrents from.

Comment: You don't seem to have tried to format it at all, you're just printing the elements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, I'm not really sure how to format it, can you tell me what Python module I should use for that? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a module? Just access the attributes of the elements you actually want, i.e. the `href`. The name and size are *outside* the elements you're getting, so you'll need to rethink your approach to see those.

Comment: @JackFleeting a magnet link looks like this:
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:b3c5a40fe8484ebfa0790bc97d5fda77c6ba0a13&amp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your code and see if it works:

```
for m in magnet:
    print(m.attrs['href'].split('dn=')[0])
```

In my case, I get the output:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:95f3f6abf3a87a19d6fec25c3b78a8ccc3890ee4&
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:2379252ac7179fd49110091eeaa962237be38b16&
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:fd4db49ba5cc5700b533c3f06a926fde237e679f&
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:b2738b271d1e547651b7cf182ea541158c6601c7&
```

etc. Note: they all end with `&`, not `&amp`, as you said they should; not sure why.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I copied your code and did the same for the Torrent info like this:


```
for n in magnet:
    print(n.attrs['title'].split('dn=')[0])
```